# Window workflow foundation 4.0 (WPF): How to change an activity location in a Flowchart workflow by code

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I use rehosting workflow designer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to load a Flowchart workflow in my application.

```
 Flowchart flowchart = this.CreateFlowchart();///Create a Flowchart workflow
 WorkflowDesigner wd = new WorkflowDesigner();
 wd.Load(flowchart);
```

How should I do to change an activity location in the Flowchart?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not a trivial task.

You effectively need to alter the location of the model item via the view state service.

```
wd.Context.Services.GetService<ViewStateService>().StoreViewStateWithUndo(modelItem, "ShapeLocation", new Point(20,20));
```

Have a read of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwinkle/archive/2009/12/06/wf4-viewstateservice.aspx) article which explains view state far better than I can.